# Comparing DataFrames of different lengths

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to filter one DataFrame by the values of another DataFrame, but can't get it to work as the filter-by-DataFrame has a different size than the to-be-filtered DataFrame. I thought I need to use `set_index` to align both DataFrames somehow, but that may be wrong.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4], 'b': [5, 3, 6, 2, 6, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'b': [3, 5, 6, 3]})
dfa = df1.set_index('a')
>>> dfa
   b
a   
1  5
1  3
2  6
3  2
3  6
4  4

dfb = df2.set_index('a')

>>> dfa[dfa['b'] <= dfb['b']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 699, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

The expected DataFrame would be `pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 3, 3], 'b': [3, 2, 6]})`:

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  3  2
2  3  6
```

(all `<a, b>` rows disappear from `df1` for which the `b` value in `df2` is <= the `b` value in `df1` and both `a` values match for `df1` and `df2`).

**Update**

A more naive way doesn't work either...

```
>>> df1[(df1['a'] == df2['a']) & (df1['b'] <= df2['b'])] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/ops.py", line 699, in wrapper
    raise ValueError('Series lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`reindex_like`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) to allign your second dataframe to `df1` size and then use your attempt with addition of [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) method instead of comparing `df1['a']` with `df2['a']`:

```
df3 = df2.reindex_like(df1)

In [93]: df1[(df3['a'].isin(df1['a'])) & (df1['b'] <= df3['b'])]
Out[93]:
   a  b
1  1  3
2  2  6
3  3  2
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
>>> df1[df1.b <= df1.a.map(dfb.b)]
   a  b
1  1  3
3  3  2
4  3  6
```

It is easier to use `df1` than `dfa` because you need `map`, which doesn't work right on indexes (only on Series).  If you absolutely need to use `dfa` instead of `dfb` then you'll have to change the second part of the comparison to `dfa.reset_index().a.map(dfb.b)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's easiest way is to use `merge` and bring the column of `df2` into `df1`.

```
>>> df2['c'] = df2['b']
>>> pd.merge(df1, df2, how='left', on=['a'])
   a  b_x  b_y  c
0  1    5    3  3
1  1    3    3  3
2  2    6    5  5
3  3    2    6  6
4  3    6    6  6
5  4    4    3  3
```

and then just do `df1[df1['b_x'] <= df1['c']]`.